# A difficult query for me

Tags: mysql

I have the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE `alarms_9_2015` (
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `point_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ALARMS_9_2015_index` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And have some records like:

```
+------------------+---------+------------+------------------------------+----------+
|       time       |   key   | point_name |           message            |  value   |
+------------------+---------+------------+------------------------------+----------+
| 22/09/2015 01:08 | 1085001 | A          | CAMBIO ESTADO DE DISPOSITIVO |  ABIERTO |
| 22/09/2015 01:09 | 1085001 | A          | RETORNO A NORMAL             |  CERRADO |
| 22/09/2015 02:09 | 1006057 | B          | CAMBIO ESTADO DE DISPOSITIVO |  ABIERTO |
| 22/09/2015 02:11 | 1085001 | A          | RETORNO A NORMAL             |  CERRADO |
| 22/09/2015 05:11 | 1012032 | C          | CAMBIO ESTADO DE DISPOSITIVO |  ABIERTO |
| 22/09/2015 05:11 | 1012032 | C          | RETORNO A NORMAL             |  CERRADO |
+------------------+---------+------------+------------------------------+----------+
```

And I want a query that give the next table:

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+
| equipo |      ABIERTO     |      CERRADO     |
+--------+------------------+------------------+
| C      | 22/09/2015 02:09 | 22/09/2015 05:11 |
| B      | 22/09/2015 05:11 |                  |
| A      | 22/09/2015 01:08 | 22/09/2015 01:09 |
| A      |                  | 22/09/2015 02:11 |
+--------+------------------+------------------+
```

Some help?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first isolate the rows with `'ABIERTO'` and `'CERRADO'` and then do a `FULL JOIN` between them. Since MySQL has not implemented `FULL` join, there are various ways to achieve such a join. We will need the distinct values of `(key, point_name)` pairs, so the easiest way seems to be to get first these values and then do two `LEFT` joins, one to `'ABIERTO'` and another to `'CERRADO'` values:

```
SELECT
    d.point_name AS equipo,
    a.time       AS abierto,
    b.time       AS cerrado
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT `key`, point_name
      FROM alarms_9_2015
    ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN
    alarms_9_2015 AS a
      ON  a.value = 'ABIERTO'
      AND a.key = d.key
      AND a.point_name = d.point_name
  LEFT JOIN
    alarms_9_2015 AS b
      ON  b.value = 'CERRADO'
      AND b.key = d.key
      AND b.point_name = d.point_name
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(a.time, b.time) ;
```

A composite index on `(key, point_name, value)` would improve efficiency.